# Error in sample() R: not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, sample

I have built the below simulation. When it is run, I get an error.

The line where the error occurs is

```
pop[j, specs, i] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
```

The specific error pertains to

```
Error in pop[j, specs, i] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs) : 
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I am unsure as to why I get the error, since everything seems to be fine to me. Because the error pertains to a line of code within an if...else statement, it is not evaluated given the values of my input parameters. Thus, there shouldn't be an issue with the code, but R still returns an error.

```
N <- 10
N1 <- N/2
N2 <- N/2

Hstar <- 5 

K <- 2 
K1 <- c(1:3)
K2 <- c(1, 4, 5)

perms <- 10 

p <- 0.95

for(i in 1:K){
    specs <- 1:get(paste0("N", i))
}

for(i in 1:K){
    if(i == 1){
        pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))
}   else{
        pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, get(paste0("N", i))), K))
  }
}

haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)

probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar) 

for(j in 1:perms){
    for(i in 1:K){ 
        if(i == 1){
            pop[j, specs, i] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
    }
        else{
            pop[j ,, 1] <- sample(haps[K1], size = N1, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[K1])
            pop[j ,, 2] <- sample(haps[K2], size = N2, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[K2])    
        }
    }
}

if(i == 1){
    HAC.mat <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))
}   else{
    HAC.mat <- array(dim = c(c(perms, get(paste0("N", i))), K))
}


for(k in specs){
    for(j in 1:perms){
        for(i in 1:K){ 
            ind.index <- sample(specs, size = k, replace = FALSE) ## which individuals will we sample
            hap.plot <- pop[sample(1:nrow(pop), size = 1, replace = TRUE), ind.index, sample(1:K, size = 1, replace = TRUE)] 
            HAC.mat[j, k, i] <- length(unique(hap.plot))
        }
    }
}


means <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, mean)
lower <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.025))
upper <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.975))

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

for(i in 1:K){
    if(i == 1){
        plot(specs, means, type = "n", xlab = "Specimens sampled", ylab = "Unique haplotypes", ylim = c(1, Hstar))
        polygon(x = c(specs, rev(specs)), y = c(lower, rev(upper)), col = "gray")
        lines(specs, means, lwd = 2)
        HAC.bar <- barplot(N*probs, xlab = "Unique haplotypes", ylab = "Specimens sampled", names.arg = 1:Hstar)
}
    else{
        plot(specs, means, type = "n", xlab = "Specimens sampled", ylab = "Unique haplotypes", ylim = c(1, max(HAC.mat)))
        polygon(x = c(specs, rev(specs)), y = c(lower, rev(upper)), col = "gray")
        lines(specs, means, lwd = 2)
        HAC.bar <- barplot(get(paste0("N", i))*probs[get(paste0("K", i))], xlab = "Unique haplotypes", ylab = "Specimens sampled", names.arg = get(paste0("K", i)))
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why this error occurs and how to go about remedying it? I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: N = 10, `str(specs)` gives `int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5`, you are sampling 10 objects and assigning them to 5 places.

Comment: @m-dz I see... is there a quick fix? Essentially I would like my subarrays in 'pop' to be of different dimensions, instead of the same size. For instance pop[,, 1] would be 2 x 10 and pop[,,2] could be 8 x 10.

Comment: Use lists then, every element can be a different matrix or df.

Comment: @m-dz Thanks! I'll try that.